# React not updating text (issue with .getDOMNode())

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React to make a Markdown previewer and trying to make sense of what was used [here](https://codepen.io/FreeCodeCamp/pen/JXrLLE?editors=0010) to make the right box update with a live preview as soon as the text is changed on the left. They have this code at the bottom:

```
var RawInput = React.createClass({
    update:function(){
        var modifiedValue=this.refs.inputValue.getDOMNode().value;
        this.props.updateValue(modifiedValue);
    },
    render:function(){
        return (<textarea rows="22" type="text" ref="inputValue" value={this.props.value} onChange={this.update} className="form-control" />)
    }
});
```

I implementing this in my code:

```
const InputText = React.createClass ({
    update() {
        let newValue = this.refs.inputValue.getDOMNode().value;
        this.props.updateValue(newValue);
    },
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <textarea 
                    id="input-text" 
                    rows="18"
                    type="text"
                    ref="inputValue"
                    value={this.props.value}
                    onChange={this.update}
                    />
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

The app runs fine except that there is no live preview and the text on the right doesn't update. In the console I get this error: `this.refs.inputValue.getDOMNode is not a function` .

Here is the full code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Banner from './components/Banner.jsx';
import ContainerHeader from './components/ContainerHeader.jsx';
import marked from 'marked';

const App = React.createClass ({
   updateValue(newValue) {
        this.setState ({
            value: newValue
        })
    },
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            value: 'Heading\n=======\n\nSub-heading\n-----------\n \n### Another deeper heading\n \nParagraphs are separated\nby a blank line.\n\nLeave 2 spaces at the end of a line to do a  \nline break\n\nText attributes *italic*, **bold**, \n`monospace`, ~~strikethrough~~ .\n\nShopping list:\n\n  * apples\n  * oranges\n  * pears\n\nNumbered list:\n\n  1. apples\n  2. oranges\n  3. pears\n'
        }
    },
    markup(value) {
        return {__html: value}
    },
    render() {
      return (
          <div>
            <Banner />
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                        <ContainerHeader text="I N P U T" />
                        <InputText 
                            value={this.state.value}
                            updateValue={this.updateValue} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                        <ContainerHeader text="O U T P U T" />
                        <div id="output-text">
                            <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.markup(marked(this.state.value))}></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      );
   }
});

const InputText = React.createClass ({
    update() {
        let newValue = this.refs.inputValue.getDOMNode().value;
        this.props.updateValue(newValue);
    },
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <textarea 
                    id="input-text" 
                    rows="18"
                    type="text"
                    ref="inputValue"
                    value={this.props.value}
                    onChange={this.update}
                    />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

export default App;
```

Any help welcome on solving this, and thanks!

Comment: What version of React are you using?

Comment: @NeilTwist 15.3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [**version `15.*`**](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/04/07/react-v15.html#removed-deprecations) in  React `this.refs.inputValue` refers to `DOMElement`, so you don't need use `getDOMNode`;

```
this.refs.inputValue.value
```

However, I think in this case you don't need use `refs`, as you call `update` inside `onChange` event, you can get `target`(refer to `textarea`) from `event` object, and from `target` get `value`

```
update(e) {
  this.props.updateValue(e.target.value);
},
```

Answer (score 2):

The example is using React v0.14.x which was one combined module.

From React v15 (0.15, but they changed to use it as the major) the methods and classes were split into two modules, React and ReactDOM.

You need to import and use `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(component)`, documentation for which can be found [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode).

Answer (score 1):

You actually do not need `this.refs.inputValue`

```
update(e) {
    this.props.updateValue(e.target.value);
},
```